Do they all have the same meaning-'make','to make','making'？


The internet has done more than simply (to) make our lives more convenient.
The implementation of these technologies has done more than making AI and ML possible.


Are there any differences among 'make','to make' and 'making'?
In Using non-finite after "but" and "except",
he said 'to make' and 'making' meant 'the activity of sitting', not an event.
But in my examples, the two are the very same usages, but with different verb forms.

'Make','to make' and 'making' are all different participles of the same verb, so they have the same root meaning but are not usually interchangeable because the tense of a verb has to fit the context and, usually, match the tense of any auxiliary verbs.

The internet has done more than simply (to) make our lives more convenient.

I presume the word 'to' is in brackets because you or someone else has added it? It shouldn't be there, it's wrong.
It's talking about what the internet has 'done', which is the past participle of the verb to do, so it is wrong to then switch to the infinitive form for the verb make. The present participle making would also be wrong.

#2 is also wrong?

"Make" and "to make" are not participles at all!!!

CGEL say that the (to) is optional there.

This doesn't make much sense. Why does the past participle require the bare infinitive "make", rather than another past participle or other verb form? "Done more than make" does seem more common, but that doesn't mean alternatives are wrong. In Art Bulletin for instance "Nauman has done more than making something of nothing".
